# create a scrollbar on entry with cavnas, python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to put a scrollbar on entry that created on canvas..
I've tried this code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x600')
root.resizable(0,0)

page = Canvas(root, width=400, height=600, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
MyImage1 = PhotoImage(file='Study With4.png')
CanvasImage = page.create_image(0,0,image= MyImage1, anchor='nw')
entry =Text(page,height=29,width =46,wrap=WORD,bg='#F8F8F8')
scroll = Scrollbar(entry, orient=VERTICAL)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scroll.config(command=page.yview)
page.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
page.create_window(200,285, window=entry)
page.pack()
mainloop()
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: If the text box is within the scroll region, the scrollbar will be deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

I've made minimal changes to your code, the biggest is creating a `Frame` called "label"
to contain `Text` and `Scrollbar` then inserting that into `Canvas` window.

Your scroll object was not defined properly with confusion around page and entry objects.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x600')
root.resizable(0,0)

page = Canvas(
    root, width = 500, height = 600, bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,scrollregion = (0,0,1000,1000))
page.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

MyImage1 = PhotoImage(file='Study With4.png')
CanvasImage = page.create_image(0, 0, image = MyImage1, anchor = NW)

label = Frame(root)
label.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

entry = Text(label, height = 29, width = 46, wrap = NONE, bg = '#F8F8F8')
entry.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

scroll = Scrollbar(label, orient = VERTICAL)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scroll.config(command = entry.yview)
entry.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)

page.pack()
page.create_window(25, 25, window = label, anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```